# How to repeat Android Animation

Tags: android, kotlin, animation

I'm trying to get two views to move to the middle of the screen and bounce back again x number of times.

This code does that but it runs only once.
`       val view = findViewById(R.id.imageView2)

```
    val animation = SpringAnimation(view, DynamicAnimation.TRANSLATION_Y, 0f)

    val view2 = findViewById<View>(R.id.imageView3)
    val animation2 = SpringAnimation(view2, DynamicAnimation.TRANSLATION_Y, 0f)

    findViewById<View>(R.id.imageView2).also { img ->
        SpringAnimation(img, DynamicAnimation.TRANSLATION_Y).apply {

            animation.getSpring().setDampingRatio(SpringForce.DAMPING_RATIO_HIGH_BOUNCY)

          
            animation.spring.stiffness = SpringForce.STIFFNESS_VERY_LOW

                animation.animateToFinalPosition(50f)
            

        }
    }
    findViewById<View>(R.id.imageView3).also { img ->
        SpringAnimation(img, DynamicAnimation.TRANSLATION_Y).apply {
            
            animation2.getSpring().setDampingRatio(SpringForce.DAMPING_RATIO_HIGH_BOUNCY)

            
            animation2.spring.stiffness = SpringForce.STIFFNESS_VERY_LOW
           
            animation2.animateToFinalPosition(-100f)
            

        }
    }`
```

So how do I get it to run x number of times?
This is obviously Spring Animation, but I'm not married to it.  If there is another animation that would accomplish this I'd be totally open to changing.

Comment: Do you mean you'd like the bouncing to happen x times or that you want to trigger the whole animation more than once?

Comment: Set the interpolator?

Comment: I mean trigger the whole animation more than once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can run multiple `SpringAnimation`s on the same `View` by repeatedly calling `animateToFinalPosition(translation)` with a sequence of *translation* values.

For example:

```
startSpringAnimations(findViewById<View>(R.id.imageView1), 300f, 6)
startSpringAnimations(findViewById<View>(R.id.imageView2), -600f, 6)
```

with a function

```
/**
 * [view] will be moved using [times] SpringAnimations over a distance of abs([totalTranslation])
 * If [totalTranslation] is negative, direction will be up, else down
 */
private fun startSpringAnimations(view: View, totalTranslation: Float, times: Int ) {
    if(times <= 0){
        return
    }

    val translation = totalTranslation/ times.toFloat()

    SpringAnimation(view, DynamicAnimation.TRANSLATION_Y, 0f).apply{
        spring.dampingRatio = SpringForce.DAMPING_RATIO_HIGH_BOUNCY
        spring.stiffness = SpringForce.STIFFNESS_VERY_LOW

        addEndListener(object: DynamicAnimation.OnAnimationEndListener{
            private var count = 1
            override fun onAnimationEnd(animation1: DynamicAnimation<*>?, canceled: Boolean, value: Float, velocity: Float) {
                Log.d("SpringAnimation", "onAnimationEnd: animation $animation1 canceled $canceled value $value velocity $velocity count $count")
                if (canceled) return

                count++
                if(count <= times){
                    animateToFinalPosition(translation * count)
                }
            }
        })
        animateToFinalPosition(translation)
    }
}
```

Comment: On my system though, this causes the animations to creep from their starting positions so that fairly quickly they run off the screen.

Comment: @JettTexas - I think one should choose values for the translations depending on the layout and the screen  size of  the  device. The important point is that before re-starting the animation one has to change the "final position"

Answer (score 0):

Set `android:repeatCount="infinite"` in anim folder